# Looping through array and assemble a string

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc-3

```
public ActionResult Create(RecurringTask recurringTask, FormCollection collection, ICollection<string> dayOfTheWeek)
```

I am trying to loop through the dayOfTheWeek (which is a group of checkboxes) and I am trying to find out which one is true so than I can use that to assemble a string ex:Monday, Tuesday, etc.

I am just having trouble finding a way of looping through my collection to do it. I keep getting can't apply == to of type string to bool error.

```
var days = dayOfTheWeek.ToString();
                    foreach (string day in dayOfTheWeek)
                    {
                        if(day == true)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    recurringTask.DaysOfTheWeek = days;
```

This is what I am thinking on how to do it. But I imagine someone out there has a way better idea than I do.  The day == true gives me that string to bool error and its obvious to why its happening, I just don't know how to get around it.

My view is this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dayOfTheWeek" value="Monday" />
<input type="checkbox" name="dayOfTheWeek" value="Tuesday" />
<input type="checkbox" name="dayOfTheWeek" value="Wednesday" />
<input type="checkbox" name="dayOfTheWeek" value="Thursday" />
<input type="checkbox" name="dayOfTheWeek" value="Friday" />
<input type="checkbox" name="dayOfTheWeek" value="Saturday" />
<input type="checkbox" name="dayOfTheWeek" value="Sunday" />
```

Comment: Are you checking the checkbox's `Caption` property, or its `Checked` property? My guess is you aren't checking the `Checked` property, because if you do `if(MyCheckbox.Checked)` that works fine.

Comment: @SpikeX - I haven't even thought of that. I'm a super newb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> public ActionResult Create(RecurringTask recurringTask, FormCollection collection, ICollection dayOfTheWeek)

Sorry to say it but that's probably one of the worst action signatures I have ever seen. A mixture of a domain model, a FormCollection and some `ICollection<string>`.

Use view models, strongly typed views and editor templates (that's probably the 10^4th time I am writing this sentence on StackOverflow  in response to questions in the `asp.net-mvc` tag)! They will make your life so much easier. So a list of days and a corresponding boolean property to indicate whether this day is selected:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<DayOfWeekViewModel> DaysOfWeek { get; set; }

    ... put any other properties that you consider useful for this view
}

public class DayOfWeekViewModel
{
    public string DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            DaysOfWeek = CultureInfo
                .CurrentCulture
                .DateTimeFormat
                .DayNames
                .Select(x => new DayOfWeekViewModel
                {
                    DayOfWeek = x,
                })
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // model.DaysOfWeek will contain all you need here
        // TODO: do some processing
        // here you can loop through model.DaysOfWeek to identify which 
        // days have been selected and take respective actions
        // ...

        // once you have finished processing you could redirect
        return RedirectToAction("success");
    }
}
```

then a corresponding view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ... you could put any other fields from your view model that
        will be used by this form here

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.DaysOfWeek)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

and the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/DayOfWeekViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model DayOfWeekViewModel

<div>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected) @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.DayOfWeek)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DayOfWeek)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I'm new to all of this. Getting stuff like this really helps me out

Answer (score 2):

The error message is revealing.  You are trying to compare a string `day` to `true` or `false`. What does it mean for a `string` to be true or false?

You really want to see if the checkboxes are checked. You claim that dayOfTheWeek is a group of `CheckBoxes`, but you are calling `ToString()` on it, which would convert it to a list of strings. What is the code before `var days = dayOfTheWeek.ToString();` Where are you declaring `dayOfTheWeek`?

Once you really have a `List<Checkbox>`, you really want to iterate through that list to see if each element is checked.

```
foreach(CheckBox cb in dayOfTheWeek)
{
    if(cb.Checked)
    {
      // Logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works in ASP.NET MVC because there usually is no `CheckBox` object.

Comment: The reason why I am calling a ToString on it is because I wan't to assemble a string after I find out if the checkbox is true/false and than save it as a string

Comment: `List<Checkbox>`? -1. That's ASP.NET MVC, not classic WebForms.

Answer (score 2):

If you named your checkboxes "dayOfTheWeek", `ICollection<string> dayOfTheWeek` only contains the selected checkboxes.

So you could just take this list as "result", but I would encourage you to filter the list of days with a list of valid values to prevent malicious attacks.